# My Java Scanner wont stop running. I was trying make a method that alphabetically sorts a string but the scanner wont stop scanning

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortAlphabetically
{
    public static String sortString(String inputString) 
    { 
        char[] stringArr = new char[inputString.length()];
        char temp;
        int n;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i ++)
        {
            stringArr[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
        }

        n = stringArr.length;

        while ( n > 1)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<(stringArr.length-1);i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j>0;j--)
                {
                    if(stringArr[j]<stringArr[j-1])
                    {
                        temp = stringArr[j-1];
                        stringArr[j-1] = stringArr[j];
                        stringArr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        String orderedWord = new String (stringArr);
        return orderedWord;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String finalWord;
        String initialWord;

        System.out.print("Please enter a word: "); // scan wont stop scanning

        initialWord = scan.nextLine();        
        finalWord = sortString(initialWord);

        System.out.println(finalWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ( n > 1)` you never change `n` inside the loop so while loop never stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to decrease `n` and therefore `while (n > 1)` remains `true` forever. Decrease `n` as follows and your program will work as expected:

```
while (n > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (stringArr.length - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j > 0; j--) {
            if (stringArr[j] < stringArr[j - 1]) {
                temp = stringArr[j - 1];
                stringArr[j - 1] = stringArr[j];
                stringArr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    n--;
}
```

On a side note, you can replace the following snippet of code

```
char[] stringArr = new char[inputString.length()];      

for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    stringArr[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
}
```

with just one line as follows

```
char[] stringArr = inputString.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I swear I went over it a million times, I don't know why I missed that thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

no issue with scanner , your while loop is running infinitely -> while(n>1) ,since n is not get decremented.